# How to perform an action only when a button is clicked in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I have created a button with an action function as you can see below but the alert messages fires before I click the action button (click me). How can I make the alert messages appear only when I click the button (click me), and not when I choose "one" in the dropdown option value.

```
<p align="center">
    <button style="height:50px;width:100px" onclick"=dropdownChange();">click me</button>
</p>

<p align="right">
    <select dir="rtl" name="test2" id="experience" onchange="dropdownChange()" >
        <option value="one"> one</option>
        <option value="five">five</option>
        <option value="six">six</option>
        <option value="seven">seven</option>
        <option value="" disabled selected>choose</option>
    </select>
    <font size="3"> number of experience</font>
</p>

<script>
function dropdownChange() {
    var experience=document.getElementById("experience").value;

    if(experience==="one") {
        alert("ok");
        document.getElementById('experience').value = "";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with this code. It should behave the way you are expecting it.

Comment: Agreed, the problem must be in the code that _isn't_ shown in the question. It's a good idea to use quotes around the `onclick` function call, as two answers have suggested, but that isn't the problem.

Comment: Could you maybe make a jsbin/jsfiddle to show it not working as expected? I agree that it should work as written

Comment: I have edited the code and i tried it  in jsbin still getting the same problem the alert message start as soon as I choose "one" from the selected option. how can I stop this behavior and make the alert only start when I click the button (click me). thank you guys for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <p align="center"><button style="height:50px;width:100px" onclick= 
dropdownChange();>click me </button></p>

<p align="right"><select dir="rtl" name="test2" id="experience" 
 >

    <option value="one"> one</option>
    <option value="five">five</option>
    <option value="six">six</option>
    <option value="seven">seven</option>
    <option value="" disabled selected>choose</option>

    </select> <font size="3"> number of experience</font>

   </p>

    <script>
     function dropdownChange() { 
        var experience=document.getElementById("experience").value;
        if(experience==="one")    {
        alert("ok");
        document.getElementById('experience').value = "";
      } 
  }
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Hi you forgot the " before and after dropdownChange().

< button style="height:50px;width:100px" onclick="dropdownChange();"  >click me < / button>

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference

Comment: Make sure that your id (age,major,experience) matche to your fields id

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, it works fine as you can see below. Post some more code, the problem is somewhere else.

```js
function dropdownChange() 
{
  var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
  var major = document.getElementById('major').value;
  var experience = document.getElementById('experience').value;

     if ( age == "" || major == "" || experience == "" ) 
      alert("fields cannot be empty!");
     else
      alert("Age: " + age + "\nMajor: " + major + "\nExperience: " + experience);
 }
```

```html
<!-- Sample elements -->
<input type="text" id="age" value="99" />
<input type="text" id="major" value="Physics" />
<input type="text" id="experience" value="Hmm" />


<p align="center"><button style="height:50px;width:100px"onclick="dropdownChange();"  >click me </button></p>
```

Comment: The quotes are not the problem. Try taking the quotes and semicolon out of your snippet. It still works!

Comment: You are right, I will re-edit. Thank you for pointing that out.